# spring-ldap and @attributes annotation with spring-ldap 2.x ODM interface

Tags: spring-ldap

There seems be some things missing in the Spring-LDAP ODM annotations. This is a question by way of a feature request, if there is a better way to contribute such requests, please say so.

I'd like to mark an @Attribute as read-only, so it will populate the bean from LDAP for reference, but not persist it back to ldap. I'd suggest adding an attribute read-only to @Attribute, defaulting to false, for the usual case. The default attributes of * misses all the operational attributes, some of which are very useful, and transfers more data than is required, slowing down the ldap query with attributes which will never be used.

An example of this; it would be very useful, for literally read only, such as entryUUID, etag, etc., which you cannot use if you wish to persist only some fields back to ldap, as the bean fails to persist to ldap with an exception when you save the bean. But also would be usefule for general fields which you want to structurally prevent the user from ever updating.

You can get around this by not annotating read-only fields, and then manually populating the read only fields with a separate call. Very messy and kills the query speed.

Also on a related topic, query() coudl have a default list of attributes, which you have already annotated in your classes, something like :

```
public static String[] getBeanAttributes(Class<?> beanClass) {
    ArrayList<String> attrsObj = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Field field : beanClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Attribute.class)) {
            Attribute attr = field.getAnnotation(Attribute.class);
            attrsObj.add(attr.name());
        }
    }
    String[] attrs = attrsObj.toArray(new String[attrsObj.size()]);
    return attrs;
}
```

Above just returns a simple String[] of your declared attributes, to pass to query.attributes() - now i realize that as a static member, query() is built before the bean class is known, but at least there could be a helper function like the above, or a method signature for query attributes() that took a bean Class signature as an argument.

Comment: I think both of your requests seek reasonable and well within reach for a future release. I would encourage you to add a request in the Jira issue tracker: https://jira.spring.io/browse/LDAP/

Comment: This is now tracked in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/issues/347. Unfortunately not yet resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I created LDAP-312 on Jira. Thanks.